# While installing mongodb realm, I can't make gradle file. I think the docs are old

Tags: java, android, mongodb, android-studio, realm

I want to use realm.io for android application but I have problems during installation

[I used these steps. I think the codes are outdated because it doesn't match my Gradle file but somehow I made it.](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/java/install/#std-label-java-install)

here is my `build.gradle (Module :app)` file

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.ig'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ig"
        minSdk 28
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

//    for MongoDB
    implementation "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:10.16.1"
}
```

I couldn't add these codes here
[this](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/java/install/#application-module-gradle-configuration)

```
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

[and this](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/java/install/#enable-atlas-device-sync)

```
realm {
    syncEnabled = true
}
```

after this stage [I wrote this code](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/java/quick-starts/quick-start-sync/#initialize-realm) [and this code](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/java/quick-starts/quick-start-sync/#initialize-the-app)

```
Realm.init(this); // context, usually an Activity or Application

app = new App(new AppConfiguration.Builder(appID)
    .build());
```

**and now getting an error message:**
[image]
[image]

***How can I resolve this error message?***

Comment: Those docs are current and accurate. Did you note this - *The Java SDK does not yet support the Gradle Plugin syntax*?

Comment: @Jay so what i can do

Comment: You can go to the [Gradle Configuration Docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/java/install/#project-gradle-configuration) and follow the steps outlined there starting with this step **Add a buildscript block** ensuring you add the required plugins, repositories and dependencies.

Comment: @Jay I added the buildscript block and added it at the top so it didn't cause any problems. Now Android Studio recognizes all the codes. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my `build.gradle (Module :app)` file as follows and now the codes are recognized by Android Studio.

```
// START[for MongoDB Realm.io]
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:10.11.1"
    }
}
// FINISH[for MongoDB Realm.io]

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

// START[for MongoDB Realm.io]
apply plugin: "realm-android"

realm {
    syncEnabled = true
}
// FINISH[for MongoDB Realm.io]

android {
    namespace 'com.example.ig'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ig"
        minSdk 28
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

*I added the buildscript block as Jay said*